# Aren't parallel calls to Task.WaitAll in separat threads executed in parallel?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, threadpool, thread-priority

I can't figure out how to control the execution of parallel calls to Task.WaitAll() which I use to execute long and short running work.
To illustrate the problem I wrote this litte test program:

```
class TaskTest
{
    private static void Work(object c)
    {
        int count = (int)c;
        //Start c Tasks which need 1s each
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Task task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(count * 20);
            });
            taskList.Add(task);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
    }


    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Work);
        thread.Start(50);
        Console.WriteLine("Long work started...");
        //ensure Worker-Thread has started to do something
        Thread.Sleep(10);

        Console.WriteLine("Start short work...");
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Work(5);
        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Time for short work: {0} s", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

        Console.WriteLine("Wait for completion of long work...");
        watch.Start();
        thread.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("Time for completion of long work: {0} s", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

A long running work is splitted into several little tasks (i.e. parallel calls to ADO.NET) which are then executed in a new thread. I use an explicit thread here to control its execution.

The main thread also does serveral things that can be splitted into litte tasks to optimize the performance. But this is "short work" in comparison with the long work (simulated by the sleep time count * 20).

To simulate the "litte tasks" I just use Thread.Sleep(1000). 
The long work starts first and tries to execute 50 little tasks.

But then I want to use Task.WaitAll() for some other work parallel in the main thread (simulated with the call of Work(5);)
I expected to get some fresh threads for these 5 little tasks in a parallel manner. But that's not the case! I have to wait for completion of the 5 tasks nearly as long as for the 50 tasks.

The console output shows the following:

```
Long work started...
Start short work...
Time for short work: 9,4921011 s
Wait for completion of long work...
Time for completion of long work: 9,9916732 s
```

So my problem is: trying to optimize a methode with separate little tasks brings the opposite result for the short work because its tasks are scheduled for later execution. But I have to wait in the main thread for the completion of them...

Is there any way to prioritise the execution of tasks? Or should I follow a different approach to control the execution of such methods with high and low workload?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Blocking threads and Tasks do not make very good room-mates. `Thread.Sleep` is an unrealistic workload, and doesn't model the asynchronicity that `Task` and/or `async/await` offer at all. Tasks are **not** threads.

Comment: If you're looking at scheduling a flow of data through different transformations, get your head properly around async/await, abandon ***all*** synchronous IO then take a look at [TPL DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: My real issue is to fill different DataTables for multiple grids and lookup-editors: there are large tables for the grids with high workload and small tables for the editors. And DataTable isn't thread-safe. So I create n new empty Rows synchronously, fill these rows with tasks asynchronously and when finished add all the rows to the DataTable. 
Do you think the DataFlow library would bring some benefits in such a case? My first impression is that it is a bit oversized for this.